# Initialize data in the beginning Wicket Application throw url parameters

Tags: java, wicket, urlrequest, wicket-1.6

Let's imagine that I have a application which is written in JSF, and I have some module which is written in Wicket. The user authorize in JSF application, and go to Wicket module throw simple link, and transfer username therein. So, the question is, how I can get that url request in Wicket application? I think that in `Application` class which is extend Wicket `WebApplication` class using `Request` class. Am i right? Where I should call that? In constructor or in the init() method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but you can `mount` links to `WebPage`s in wicket. This is done in the WebApplication `init()`

```
public void init() {
  super.init();
  mountPage("/succes", SuccessPage.class);
}
```

You can access the parameters that are passed on to the link by using the following constructor of the `Page`

```
public class SuccessPage extends WebPage {

    public SuccessPage(final PageParameters parameters) {

        String username = "";

        if(parameters.containsKey("username")){
            username = parameters.getString("username");
        }

    }
}
```

So you can do:

```
GET /succes?username=COOLUSER34
```

More information on urls in wicket: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/urls.html